# Why is MySQL not properly naming my foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, create-table

Please consider the following SQL code that I run in MySQL 8.0.22 (in an InnoDB database):

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `person_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `pet` (
  `pet_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pet_id`)
);

ALTER TABLE `pet`
  ADD COLUMN `owner_id` smallint unsigned;

ALTER TABLE `pet`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_pet_person`
  FOREIGN KEY `idx_fk_pet_person` (`owner_id`)
  REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`);

SHOW CREATE TABLE pet;
```

The output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE pet` is:

```
CREATE TABLE `pet` (
  `pet_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` smallint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pet_id`),
  KEY `fk_pet_person` (`owner_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pet_person` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

In the output above, why is the KEY named `fk_pet_person` when I specified its name as `idx_fk_pet_person` in my `ALTER TABLE` command? How can I get it to be named so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the FOREIGN KEY and the INDEX that makes it work. Pay attention - there is NO expression name (which looks like an index definition but is not) in the constraint definition displayed in your code.

When there is no suitable index for the constraint to work, then this index is auto-created, and the constraint name is used as the index name. If a suitable index exists, then auto-creation does not occur.

If you want the index to have a defined name then you must create this index in a separate `ALTER TABLE` (sub)statement before the constraint creation:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `pet`
  ADD KEY `idx_fk_pet_person` (`owner_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_pet_person`
  FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`)
  REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`);
```

or

```sql
ALTER TABLE `pet`
  ADD KEY `idx_fk_pet_person` (`owner_id`);

ALTER TABLE `pet`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_pet_person`
  FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`)
  REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ecbc0225bf32aaa34f2f437332eef1c)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. Your workaround would work. I am not confusing FK and constraint however.  My answer explains two reasons why my code does not set the index name as I expected.

Comment: @urig *I am not confusing FK and constraint however.* I have told about FK and index. Not about FK and constraint - FK is one of the types of constraints. Constraint is an instruction/rule (and it has no physical implementation) whereas index is static storing structure and its data.

Comment: @urig See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75ef378129ff8559c9e952f370f3ee8a additionally.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL documentation specifies this syntax for creating a foreign key:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT
```

There are two reasons why my code does not set the `[index_name]` and instead the index name is automatically made the same as the constraint name. Both are evident from this paragraph taken from the MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual, section [13.1.20.5 FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Prior to MySQL 8.0.16, if the CONSTRAINT symbol clause was not defined, or a symbol was not included following the CONSTRAINT keyword, both InnoDB and NDB storage engines would use the FOREIGN_KEY index_name if defined. In MySQL 8.0.16 and higher, the FOREIGN_KEY index_name is ignored.

The first reason is that I am running the code in MySQL 8.0.22.

The second reason is that I should have omitted the constraint name.

The workarounds in @akina's answer indeed enable me to specify a name for the foreign key (index) that is different from the constraint's name.

Comment: Your code gives the same output in both 8.0 and 5.6/ https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.6&fiddle=59fc9dfc0ed9007f240052038be39906

Comment: @akina you're right. That's because I specified the constraint name in my code. Only if it's omitted will MySQL use the specified index name for the index.